# How to have app names be spoken aloud on a new notification?

Tags: notifications, automation, accessibility, text-to-speech

How can app names be spoken aloud on a new notification? For example: if I receive an email, I'd like to hear the word "Gmail" spoken aloud.

I could use TalkBack for this, but then the entire notification is read aloud (including parts of the email's content). I want to hear just the app's name. Also, I'd like it to work even when TalkBack is off (I use TalkBack intermittently because of my visual impairment).

Is there a way to do this?

I'm on Android 13 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroi) is a free ( upto 5 macros) [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app

Create a macro as below (name it whatever and save  it)

[image]

If you want to vary the speed or pitch of reading out, change it here

[image]

Be warned that it may get to be annoying if you get many notifications or it's bothering those around you. In that case, go to the three dot menu at top right and **Disable macro** or decrease volume level.

You can also create a short cut to this macro from your launcher settings and select MacroDroid short cut.

Tested on Pixel 6a, Android 13.

---

Edit in response to comments (now deleted), but self-explanatory

1. The shortcut as mentioned earlier in to only easily access the macro if you wish to toggle it on/off.
2. You can create another macro and add it as a shortcut on your home screen to enable/disable the macro. I named it **simple** toggle with a reason. You can add IF conditions to flash a text message and read out if the macro is enabled or disabled state (home work for you, if you want)

[image]

3. It (the first macro) will NOT override DND. If you do not wish this in the constraints section of the first macro add *Priority mode/ DND* → *Not in mode*
4. To exclude apps like Twilight etc which are constantly in monitoring mode and are announced because of this macro - in the first macro trigger section instead of selecting **all** Apps choose only those you wish to be notified for. Similarly in the *While/do* loop select the apps you wish instead of *all apps*

Comment: Thanks! Experimenting with this now. Could you please explain why the While/do loop is needed at all?

Comment: Simple-as long as a notification from the selected app is present, read out the apps name. IF loop can also be used, but this is more elegant and gives you more configurations if you look closely when you set up a while loop

Comment: In other words actions are performed conditionally. While loop describes those conditions

Comment: I see! In my case, I don't need the loop - I just want to have the app name spoken *once* - when the notification first appears. Seems to work well so far, so I'm marking it accepted :)